# How to get message from E11000 DuplicationKeyError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, flask, pymongo

So I am writing unittests for a project and I am testing `register()` function.

Here is it:

```
def register():
    # Get information about user
    username = request.get_json().get("username")
    password = request.get_json().get("password")
    name = request.get_json().get("name")
    email = request.get_json().get("email")

    # Put information about user in a tuple
    values = (
        None, 
        username, 
        User.hash_password(password), 
        name,
        email,
        None
    )

    try:
        # Create user and update session
        User(*values).create()
        ActiveUser.logged_in = True
        ActiveUser.username = username
        info_log.info("User %s registered successfully." % username)

        return jsonify(success=True, message="Registration successful!")

    except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError as e:
        # Catch pymongo exception
        return jsonify(success=False, message="Duplicated username or email!"), 403
```

I want to have three tests: valid, invalid (duplicate username), invalid (duplicate email).

```
# Register helper function
def register(self, username, password, name, email):
    return self.app.post(
        "/register",
        data = json.dumps(dict(username = username, password = password, name = name, email = email)),
        content_type='application/json',
        follow_redirects = True
        )

def test_02_valid_user_registration(self):
    response = self.register('test', '12345678', 'Tester 1', 'test@mail.mail')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertIn(b'Registration successful!', response.data)

def test_03_invalid_user_registration_duplicate_username(self):
    response = self.register('test', '12345678', 'Tester 2', 'test1@mail.mail')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
    self.assertIn(b'Duplicate username or email!', response.data)

def test_04_invalid_user_registration_duplicate_email(self):
    response = self.register('test2', '12345678', 'Tester 3', 'test@mail.mail')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
    self.assertIn(b'Duplicate username or email!', response.data)
```

As expected I get DuplicateKeyError, because I have set Unique for those parameters in the database.

```
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: user.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: "test" }
```

Is there a way to get which is the duplicated item from the DuplicateKeyError, so I can have separate unit tests for duplicate username and email?

> I know this is more of a component/integration testing rather than unit testing, but this is the only way I know how to do it in Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I started digging through the implementation of DuplicateKeyError and I found that it contains `code` and `details`.

I printed the `details` of the error and got this:

```
{
    "message": {
        "code": 11000,
        "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: user.users index: username_1 dup key: { 
            username: \"test\" 
        }",
        "index": 0,
        "keyPattern": {
            "username": 1
        },
        "keyValue": {
            "username": "test"
        }
    },
    "success": false
}
```

After that it was easy to get the two tests to work.

```
try:
    # code
except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError as e:
    # Catch pymongo exception
    key = list(e.details.get("keyValue").keys())[0]
    value = e.details.get("keyValue").get(key)
    return jsonify(success=False, message="Duplicate %s: %s" % (key, value)), 403
```

And the tests:

```
def test_03_invalid_user_registration_duplicate_username(self):
    response = self.register("test", "12345678", "Tester 2", "test1@mail.mail")
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
    self.assertIn(b"Duplicate username: test", response.data)

def test_04_invalid_user_registration_duplicate_email(self):
    response = self.register("test", "12345678", "Tester 3", "test@mail.mail")
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
    self.assertIn(b"Duplicate email: test@mail.mail", response.data)
```